# Deleting shapefiles with its belongings in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, delete

In the Browser it's not possible to delete shapefiles. In ArcMap you can delete shapefiles easily within the ArcCatalog.

How can I delete shapefiles in QGIS without minimizing the QGIS Window, navigating to the folder on my computer, select all the files that belong to a shapefile (*shp*, *dbf*, *shx*, *prj*, etc.) and delete it?

Comment: Are you using QGIS Browser, or QGIS Desktop?

Comment: I use QGIS Desktop.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible in the GUI, and IMO that's appropriate.

Comment: You can install ArcGis - in ArcGisCatalog select the file and press >delete<

Comment: Where can I download ArcGIS with ArcCatalog ready to install and use, @frmante?

Comment: Feature Request raised, though I figured the code from various answers would vary a little with the changes to QGIS 3.  Qt5, PyQt 5, Python 3 ect...  
[Delete layers/files rather than remove](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19832)

Comment: This actually is possible now - see [my answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/414916/34517). I support the raised feature request 100%, but it asks for a little more than this question (being able to delete via layers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my QGIS 3.14 this seems to be implemented. Using the integrated "Browser", you have the option to right-click -> Delete File.

**This will also remove `.dbf`, `.prj` and `.shx` for a selected `.shp`-File.**

[image: QGIS Delete File for shapefile]

I have been waiting for this as well and am glad that it finally works like ArcMap Catalog.
The [feature request](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/27656) to delete directly via layer (delete the source-file of a layer) mentioned below [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/190431/34517) is still pending though.

Answer (score 6):

There is a built-in function for this in the QGIS API.

Select your layer in the Layers panel, then open the Python console and run the following:

```
from qgis.core import QgsVectorFileWriter

layer = iface.activeLayer() # If no layer selected, it will be empty and make the end of the script failed
shp_path = layer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri().split('|')[0]
print (QgsVectorFileWriter.deleteShapeFile(shp_path)) # Should return True if really deleted
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you can do this using the GUI but you can certainly do this using the **Python Console**. The following code goes into the specified path and **deletes all files** beginning with "File_Name":

```
import glob, os
path = 'path/to/folder//'

for fname in glob.glob(path + "File_Name.*"):
    os.remove(fname)
```

---

**Edit**:

Responding to the comment from @GermánCarrillo, you should enter the filename in full and then add a `.` at the end as shapefiles (in most cases atleast) end with different extensions after the `.`. So now there should be less chance of you deleting shapefiles which contain similar names.

Comment: That could be a bit dangerous. You might want to delete a file whose name turns out to be a prefix for other files, e.g., deleting "boundary" while having "boundary_country" in the same folder.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo - Indeed it could be, I've edited the post to include a minor addition which should help a little to avoid deleting other files with similar names =)

Answer (score 3):

Building on [Joseph's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/190294/115), you can delete any file in the Python console.

This is a little script that will delete all the files with a shapefile-associated extension in the directory of the 'foo.shp' file you give it:

```
import os, argparse

def deleteShapefile(aDir, aFile):

    fnameNoExt = os.path.splitext(aFile)[0]

    extensions = ["shp", "shx", "dbf", "prj", "sbn", "sbx", "fbn", "fbx", "ain", "aih", "ixs", "mxs", "atx", "xml", "cpg", "qix"]

    theFiles = [f for f in os.listdir(aDir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(aDir, f))] # get list of all files in that directory

    for f in theFiles:
        theFile = os.path.basename(f)
        name, extension = os.path.splitext()
        # If the name matches the input file and the extension is in that list, delete it:
        if (name == fnameNoExt or name == fnameNoExt + ".shp") and (extension in extensions): # handles the foo.shp.xml case too.
            os.remove f

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="A path to a file assumed to be a shapefile, this deletes all files in the same directory that have extensions possible in shapefile subfiles.")
    parser.add_argument('SHAPEFILENAME')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    realpath = os.path.realpath(args.SHAPEFILENAME)
    theDir, theFile = os.path.split(realpath)
    deleteShapefile(os.path.basename(realpath))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You could run that in a command terminal if you saved it as a .py file with something like

```
$ python deleteshapefile.py myshapefile.shp
```

If you find yourself doing it a lot, you could put that .py file somewhere on the path given in your environment variable PYTHON_PATH and just import it in the console inside QGIS, in which you just call `deleteShapefile(aDir, aFile)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this using the terminal and appropriate use of wildcards. For example, in bash running:

rm 'path/to/file'.*

will erase all the shapefile associated files for a particular file. It can be a bit dangerous though if you're not careful. I always try to be good and run the ls command (e.g., ls 'path/to/file'.*) to return a list of all files captured by the wildcard before removing them (for example, if you happen to have a .tif with the same file name that you don't want to erase as well).

That'd probably make a good feature request though!

Comment: Feature Request raised, though I figured the code from various answers would vary a little with the changes to QGIS 3.  Qt5, PyQt 5, Python 3 ect...  
[Delete layers/files rather than remove](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19832)