# Deleting shapefile with QGIS?

Tags: shapefile, pyqgis, delete

This is a follow-up question to an [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/200938/85247) to [Deleting Shapefiles using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190283/deleting-shapefiles-using-qgis)

I tried to run the script, however it always returns `False` and the shapefile is not deleted - any ideas what needs to be changed in order to make it work?

This is what it looks like:

```
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    layer
    <qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x0000000012DFC1E0>
    shp_path = layer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri().split('|')[0]
    shp_path
    u'C:/GIS/GIS_Kirchenkreise/13 GIS/Grundlagen/Daten_aufbereitet/Wahlkreise_Test.shp'
    print (QgsVectorFileWriter.deleteShapeFile(shp_path))
    False
```

Comment: Tested on GNU/Linux with QGIS 2.18 and works like a charm. Is the Shapefile open by another program (other programs may lock the Shapefile)? Do you have read AND write permissions on that folder/file?

Comment: Thanks @Germán for testing! I work with QGIS 2.14 (Windows) and I think I have all permissions and no other programs locking the shapefile. Running the script again I realised that the `prj`, the `qpj` and the `shx` files are deleted, however the `dbf` and the `shp` files remain. I guess that at least something is happening

Comment: Testet with QGIS 2.14 (Windows) works fine too.

Comment: I have the same issue @Stephanie : `.prj`, `.qpj` and `.shx` are deleted but `.shp` and `.dbf` remain. I'm using `QGIS 3.10.2`