# .deleteShapeFile isn't delete cpg files

Tags: pyqgis

Following [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190283/deleting-shapefiles-using-qgis/190294#190294) answer.

I notice that the cpg (decoding declaration) file isn't delete using .deleteShapeFile pyQgis function.

Any suggestion on how to delete these files using automatic method?